# What does each indexed field from `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` mean?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I keep seeing tutorials and explanations, all based on [the standard javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html).

For example:

> java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%1$tc %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n"
> This prints 2 lines where the first line includes the timestamp (1$) and the source (2$); the second line includes the log level (4$) and the log message (5$)

So I guess that if (for *whatever* reason) I want to put the message before everything else, I just put `5$` at the beginning.

Where can I find a detailed explanation of what each of those numbered fields mean?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)

Comment: By the way, some links on that page are broken. The formatter options shouldn't have change since java 11, so you can take a look at the [current](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) documentation for `Formatter`, which is what is used under the hood.

Comment: The link you post in your question documents it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JavaDocs you linked](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) will show it as the function args, but if you ignore the first one the rest line up in place:

1. date - a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object representing [event time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getMillis()) of the log record.
2. source - a string representing the caller, if available; otherwise, the logger's name.
3. logger - the logger's name.
4. level - the [log level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html#getLocalizedName()).
5. message - the formatted log message returned from the [Formatter.formatMessage(LogRecord)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html#formatMessage(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) method. It uses [java.text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) formatting and does not use the java.util.Formatter format argument.
6. thrown - a string representing the [throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getThrown()) associated with the log record and its backtrace beginning with a newline character, if any; otherwise, an empty string.

For example, with the format you had:

`%1$tc %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n`

It would be the timestamp, source, a newline, the log level, the log message, then the backtrace

Comment: So answer was right under my nose... thank you :)